# obtaining substring from square bracket in a sentence

Tags: python

I would like to ask as a python beginner, I would like to obtain strings from inside a square bracket and best if without trying to import any modules from python. If not it's okay.

For example,

```
def find_tags
    #do some codes


x = find_tags('Hi[Pear]')
print(x)
```

it will return

```
1-Pear
```

if there are more than one brackets for example,

```
x = find_tags('[apple]and[orange]and[apple]again!')
print(x)
```

it will return

```
1-apple,2-orange,3-apple
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out thanks!

Comment: Can you use Regex?

Comment: What would `[[foo]]` expect to return? what have you tried?

Comment: Assume that they only takes in one [] and not multiple [[]].

Comment: I try to avoid regex.

Comment: I'm new to python, and i only know the basics of python programming, i'm not advanced as you and i came here seeking help. @baris,

Comment: I know, I'm not trying to be mean. But there are many questions on SO that can help you put together the building blocks for this question and I don't see that effort.

Comment: no worries @baris, i am stuck with how to proceed, I can use the SPLIT function or FIND function but both i am unable to get what is inside the [ ]. That's why i cancelled my code and seek help here.

Comment: Break it down into sub-problems. Try to solve these individually first. Then proceed plugging them together, e.g., start by passing the string to a function that does nothing, then produce a list of all substrings starting with `[`, then find those that contain a `]`, and so on. You will learn what you need along the way. Don't overthink this. It is just a toy example to get you learn some basic string and list handling in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I tried solving it. Here is my code :

```
bracket_string = '[apple]and[orange]and[apple]again!'

def find_tags(string1):
  start = False
  data = ''
  data_list = []
  for i in string1:
    if i == '[':
      start = True
    if i != ']' and start == True:
      if i != '[':
        data += i
    else:
      if data != '':
        data_list.append(data)
      data = ''
      start = False
  return(data_list)

x = find_tags(bracket_string)
print(x)
```

The function will return a list of items that were between brackets of a given string parameter.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your input, can i ask one more thing from you? can you explain why do you begin with start = False? and does your for loop "for i in string1 (i think its string1 not par1), is it better if it's "for ch in string 1"?

Comment: Changed that. Should have been string1 instead of par1. Yeah, you could change i `for i in string1` to anything you want. It's preference. As for the `start = False` at the beginning, I created a variable with the boolean value `False`, because I have a habit of pre-creating the variables I will use. Just a habit to save possible errors. For example, if we had `bracket_string = 'zzz[apple]and[orange]and[apple]again!'` Notice I added three `zzz` at the beginning of the string, Python will bring this error : `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start' referenced before assignment`

Comment: We wouldn't want to depend on a `if` operation to initiate our variables. It's better pre-initiating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a simple for loop over all characters of your text.

You have to remember if you are *inside* a tag or *outside* a tag - if inside you add the letter to a temporary list, if you encounter the end of a tag, you add the whole templorary list as word to a return list.

You can solve the numbering using [`enumerate(iterable, start=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) of the list of words:

```
def find_tags(text):
    inside_tag = False
    tags = []   # list of all tag-words
    t = []      # list to collect all letters of a single tag
    for c in text:
        if not inside_tag:
            inside_tag = c == "["    # we are inside as soon as we encounter [
        elif c != "]":            
            t.append(c)              # happens only if inside a tag and not tag ending
        else:
            tags.append(''.join(t))  # construct tag from t and set inside back to false
            inside_tag = False
            t = []                   # clear temporary list

    if t: 
        tags.append(''.join(t))      # in case we have leftover tag characters ( "[tag" )

    return list(enumerate(tags,start=1))  # create enumerated list 


x = find_tags('[apple]and[orange]and[apple]again!')

# x is a list of tuples (number, tag):
for nr, tag in x:
    print("{}-{}".format(nr, tag), end = ", ")
```

Then you specify ',' as delimiter after each print-command to get your output.

`x` looks like: `[(1, 'apple'), (2, 'orange'), (3, 'apple')]`

Comment: To be specific, I was most uncomfortable with the mixed case variable names and the amount of inline comments. Also the whitespace in some of the statements seems inconsistent. But probably that's a matter of personal preference overall.

Comment: @moooeeeep I can accomodate the mixed cased variable names, the inline comments are for educational purposes only. thanks for suggesting it. I found some other things in pep8

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is consistent like `[sometext]sometext[sometext]...` you can implement your function like this:

```
import re

def find_tags(expression):
   r = re.findall('(\[[a-zA-Z]+\])', expression)
   return ",".join([str(index + 1) + "-" + item.replace("[", "").replace("]", "") for index, item in enumerate(r)])
```

Btw you can use stack data structure (FIFO) to solve this problem.